# Using SVN and Remote Synchronization with another server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-pdt

I use SVN repository for my [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/mars1) project in Eclipse Mars 4.5, but also it's necessary to synchronize all changes with dev remote server (not SVN repo) on the fly. Remote server is used because it has needed environment + database which should be tested, so for development using of this server is preferable.

Now I have project from the SVN repo ([**Subversive**](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)) and on every change, if need to see results, I must export files from the project to the dev-server (**Remote System Explorer**), if I make synchronization (to make changes be uploaded automatically) it removes SVN settings from the project.

Is it possible to use both?

Comment: Can you deploy your code to production from svn?

Comment: @Y.N Yes, but I need that code (co from repo and changed by me localy) to be synchronized with the remote server (dev) continuously before I perform a commit.

Comment: Can you use the branch for it?

Comment: @Y.N But this won't ease the process, instead of constantly exporting the project to the remote server, now I will have to commit to branch and than check out from it for every change? This sounds weird, doesn't it. I want automate synchronization so I don't have to do redundant actions manually.

Comment: You can configure the svn update from branch on your test remote server, and then testing is complete then merge branch to main trunk on your local dev machine

Comment: @Y.N Thanks for reply, this sounds as a solution. But I'm developing code constantly checking the results of my work, so make commit to the branch on variable renaming, or checking if IoC is resolving a new class is irrationally.

Comment: I think your code is too fragile. For svn deploy start to read from here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/deploy-repository-to-production-server